# How to locate this javascript prompt?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, prompt

There is an old website whose server-side pages are writen by ASP:

> www.xxxx.com:8080/teacherNew/MyHomePage.asp

After I log in it, I can find a block of javascript code as follows:

```
function   Login(url){  
    var u = "xxx";
    var p = "pppp";
    
    if(myBrowser()=="IE"){
        //do nothing
    }else{ 
        var url_new = url.replace("https://","https://"+u+":"+p+"@").replace("http://","http://"+u+":"+p+"@");
        window.open(url_new);
        return;
    }

      
    var objXMLHttp=new   ActiveXObject("msxml2.xmlhttp");   
    objXMLHttp.open("POST",url,false,u,p);   
    objXMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
          
        if (objXMLHttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (objXMLHttp.Status >=200 && objXMLHttp.Status <406) {
                window.open(url,'_blank');
            }else{
                alert(objXMLHttp.status+"Failure");
            } 
        } 
    };
    objXMLHttp.send(null);   
}
```

However, such code is called by a prompt, which appears **only imediately** when I access
`www.xxxx.com:8080`, and this page is **blank** before I input correct user_id(for u) and password(for p).

Now there is a question: how can I locate this prompt? Thanks a lot!

PLUS. The page is **blank** means that its source code is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Chrome version: 91.0.4472.106

Comment: That prompt isn't invoked via JavaScript, but via the `WWW-Authenticate` header.

Comment: Where is `var u = "xxx"; var p = "pppp";` coming from. You mention a dialog, but that code indicates the data is already present. Maybe it's written by server-side code?